# Displaying one node for each unique field reference in View (e.g. one videogame for each developer)

Tags: 7, views

I have an view that display my custom content type (e.g. covers of video game titles).

Lets assume that I have this structure for my content types:

```
developer
|--title
|--country
...

video game
|--title
|--body
|--developer_ref (term reference, as choice list)
...
```

It works ok except for one thing. I want to display only one video game per developer here (the newest one).

So for example, if we have 3 different developers I want to display 3 items and each of it its the latest node referenced to each developer.

I know how to display 3 latest nodes, but that way they can e.g. all come from one developer.

I have already tried with agreegation on `video game.developer_ref` field:
[image]

But I don't know why it doesn't change a thing (I still see multiple games for some developers).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

This unfortunately only works if your developers were users. After reading your question again, it appears you have created them as content, in which case my answer does not work.

---

Views has a built-in feature for this called 'Representative node'. This can be used to

> Obtains a single representative node for each user, according to a
>   chosen sort criterion.

So how to use this:

- Start off by creating a view that lists `users` and add the `Representative node` relationship (in the advanced section).
- Configure the selection criteria; in your case this would be 'Content: Authored on'.

[image]

This adds a relationship to Views, allowing you to add fields to the view.
If you want to show the rendered node instead of individual fields, add the `Rendered entity` field instead:

[image]

No need for aggregation.

*Do note that this will always fetch the last node the user has created of every content type. You should add additional filters to the view to limit this to game-nodes, etc.*